Where to find the Grover's algorithm for Qiskit 1.0.2?
Can anyone please provide me with the latest version of qiskit 1.0.2 Grover's algorithm, as the earlier version is throwing an error.

Grover's algorithm is now part of a separate package qiskit-algorithms that must be installed separately.
The documentation for the latest version is here, and here are some examples.
